# How to get to specific method of object stored in collection?

Tags: java, interface

This sounds like a basic stuff and I cannot get it work.

Let's assume I need an application that stores all the workers in my company. They do different stuff and the price for their job depends on the specifics of the profession. For each worker I need a price.

What I do:

Create an interface of a Worker

```
public interface Worker {
    int getPrice(); 
}
```

Create a class of LanguageTranslator who's salary depends on NumberOfLines of text which is translated. The class implements Worker. Of course, for other proffesions I will have other factors influencing the price.

```
public class LanguageTranslator implements Worker {

    private int numberOfLines;

        @Override
        public int getPrice() {
            return this.numberOfLines * 14;
        }

        public void setNumberOfLines(int numberOfLines) {
            this.numberOfLines = numberOfLines;
        }   
    }
```

And now, I want to store all the workers in a List, Map or whatever collection and have direct access to setNumberOfLines method.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();
        Worker worker = new LanguageTranslator();
        workers.add(worker);

        //How to get to LanguageTranslator.setNumberOfLines() method?

    }
}
```

If I go directly to the collection

```
workers.get(0).[only interface methods visible];
```

only interface methods are available. Is there any way to get to the specific LanguageTranslator methods?

I suppose this may be very bad design. Any keywords I could search for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to use a List of LanguageTranslator instead of Worker.

Comment: Yes, I could, but if I have later another professions like Accountant, Manager, Lawyer, etc. and want to keep them in one collection, your solution will not do.

Comment: Then you would need to cast each object as you get it. `((LanguageTranslator)workers.get(0)).setNumberofLines();`

Comment: It's already a poor design even prior to solving this problem. 'Number of lines' isn't a property of a translator, it is a property of a translation, i.e. a specific piece of work.

Comment: Good point. So here comes the broader issue. Each Worker, regardless of type, needs different piece of information to assess its price. What design pattern to use in order to pass different parameters to different types of Worker?

Comment: Maybe you need a `Work` interface, and various classes that implement `Work` in appropriate ways, and a `setWork()` method, or maybe just `getPrice(Work)`.

Comment: @EJP I like this one, I'll test it tomorrow (it's 1.30 am here). Assuming another scenario: Translator has property SpeedOfTranslation, Accountant has property Experience. They're both Workers and based on their respective properties they calculate the Price. Would it then be my design correct?

Comment: You don't need to change it further to accomodate that.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to cast each object as you get it from the list. In the comments you mentioned that you'll have different professions that will later be added. Since you don't know which type to cast it as, you'll need to check.

```
Object object = workers.get(0);
if(object instanceof LanguageTranslator) {
    LanguageTranslator lt = (LanguageTranslator) object;
    lt.setNumberOfLines(7);
}
else if(object instanceof Accountant) {
    Accountant acc = (Accountant) object;
    acc.doSomething();
}
etc...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that all instances that are of a `LanguageTranslator` type are also of a `Worker` type, but not all instances that are of a `Worker` type are also of a `LanguageTranslator` type. Therefore you can't call `LanguageTranslator` methods on all `Worker` instances.

You can cast instances of a `Worker` type to a `LanguageTranslator` type, but you must always check if that instance really is a of `LanguageTranslator` type first.

```
if(worker instanceof LanguageTranslator) {
    ((LanguageTranslator) worker).setNumberOfLines(1);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. Thanks!